# how cut strings after a specific word?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a columns of texts. How I can cut the part of each text after the term `show less`?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['hi there see less new way is comming','today is summer, see less , is a lovely day']})
```

that looks like:

```
col 
'hi there see less new way is comming'
'today is summer, see less , is a lovely day'
```

output:

```
col 
'hi there'
'today is summer,'
```

Comment: What is it that you tried for this?

Comment: I am not familiar with pandas function. I can do with `for` loop but I thought there might be a function for that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.split` to split on `see less` and then use str slicing to take the first part.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.split('see less').str[0]
```

Output:

```
                 col
0          hi there 
1  today is summer,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regex and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('see less.*', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
                 col
0          hi there 
1  today is summer,
```

If you also want to remove the non-letter character just before:

```
df['col'].str.replace(r'\W+see less.*', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
               col
0         hi there
1  today is summer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract('(.*)\s*see less')
print(df)

# Output
                 col
0          hi there 
1  today is summer,
```